# Chat application using parse

Tags: iphone, ios6, chat

While working with chat application I found the tutorial [Chat using parse](http://attila.tumblr.com/post/21180235691/ios-tutorial-creating-a-chat-room-using-parse-com), using the same ApplicationID and  Client Key I am not able to chat two devices, should I use separate id for both? Can any one please help me out with some references or any chat application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion you should try it with separate ID for both. By the way I am developing an app, it will be a VoIP app (according a sample that you can find if you Google on: voip-sip-sdk/p_457). In case you are interested check it out.

Comment: can yu pls give ne the link